# How work with $(target) inside directive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I build a directive for time selection with two blocks. Problem is to catch target event on some blocks inside directive template.
Directive template:

```
<div class='time-picker-container'>
    <div class='block1' ng-click='show()'>1</div>
    <div class='block2' ng-show='selectVisible'>2</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
scope.selectVisible = false;
scope.show = function() {
    scope.selectVisible = scope.selectVisible ? false : true;
}
$rootScope.$on('documentClicked', function(inner, target) {
    //try to hide div.block2 if user make click outside block.
});
```

Basic idea: when user make click on document, outside div.block2, block disappear. When user click somewere inside div.block2 block stay visible.

On run function:

```
angular.element(document).on('click', function(e) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('documentClicked', angular.element(e.target));
    });
```

Comment: Is there already a  broadcast somewhere for `documentClicked` ? Would help to have that event object to work with

Comment: yes, on run function. I edited post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template, add `$event` as an argument to the `ng-click` handler function.

```
<div class='time-picker-container'>
    <div class='block1' ng-click='show($event)'>1</div>
    <div class='block2' ng-show='selectVisible'>2</div>
</div>
```

Then in your `ng-click` handler use `stopPropagation()` to prevent the `outsideClickHandler` from getting called.

```
angular.module("myApp").controller("myVm", function($scope, $document) {
    var vm = $scope;
    vm.selectVisible = false;

    vm.show = function(event) {
       console.log("inside click");
       event.stopPropagation();
       vm.selectVisible = vm.selectVisible ? false : true;
    }

    function outsideClickHandler(e) {
        console.log("outside click");
        $scope.$apply("selectVisible = false");
    }
    $document.on("click", outsideClickHandler);

    $scope.$on("destroy", function() {
        $document.off("click", outsideClickHandler)
    })
})
```

To prevent memory leaks, be sure to remove the $document click handler when the scope is destroyed.

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p5ezfzmm/).